# Infrastructure to effectively set up experiements and learn from them

Tags: website-design, analytics

My website is in the early stages of creating our first product, a place on the web, where one can ask lawyers questions at a fraction of their normal costs.

I got inspired by [this video](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/visualizing-code-to-fail-faster.html), which is recommended by Jeff Atwood, which talks about getting feedback faster, which is the reason for this question.

**The problem**
Needless to say, we want our conversion rates to be as high as possible. Therefore, we want to be able to rapidly set up a new experiment where we change something on the site (like moving an image slightly, rewriting a sentence etc.). We then want to present the modified page to a random subset of the users. After that we will compare the conversion rates of the experiment with another version. I could very well imagine that we want to run 10-100 experiments simultaneously and it would be nice to have features, where experiments that obviously have worse results will be ended before schedule.

**My question**
Does infrastructure to support the whole process exist?

A short description of our infrastructure... We use EC2 and PHP and have [a script](http://forum.open-org.com/q158/Create-simple-webpage-which-will-start-Python-script) to automatically start up new instances with all needed software. Still, starting up a new server for every experiment, seems like a bit of overkill, so I am wondering what other options exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [A/B Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing). [Google website optimizer](https://www.google.com/analytics/siteopt/exptlist?account=20585450&hl=en) offers this feature for free.